# Using Sed To Read Last 6 Lines In A Directory

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, awk, sed

I'm currently trying to use Sed to read the last (most recent) 6 lines in a web directory, located at http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/rtma/prod/rtma2p5.20140522/.

I'm currently experimenting with an older code but, it doesn't seem to be getting me very far...

```
wget -q -O - http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/rtma/prod/rtma2p5.20140522/ |
grep '<a href=' | tail -6 | sed -e 's/.*\(rtma2p5.t[0-9]*z.2dvaranl_ndfd.grb2\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Try `sort -r` to get the files in reverse order and then `sed -n '1,6 { ... }'`?  Going backwards in `sed` is messy at best (at least in standard `sed`); you can't use line number offsets (so you can't use `$-5,$`).

Comment: Could you be clearer about your expectations? Do you want the last six lines which match the filename pattern `rtma2p5.t[0-9]*z-2dvaranl_ndfd.grb2`, with just the file pattern showing up? Or do you want the instances of that filename pattern in the last six lines?

Comment: Basically, I would like to grab the filenames of the 6 most recent files in that directory and then output them to a text file.

Comment: What is the output of your `wget` command and what is your expected output from it.

Comment: The wget output is: "rtma2p5.t23z.2dvaranl_ndfd.grb2
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="rtma2p5.t23z.2dvaranl_nwrfc.grb2">rtma2p5.t23z.2dvaranl_nwrfc.grb2</a></td><td align="right">22-May-2014 19:50  </td><td align="right">9.8M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" when it should just be the file name 'rtma2p5.t23z.2dvaranl_ndfd.grb2"

Answer (score 1):

Horses for courses.

```
wget -q -O - http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/rtma/prod/rtma2p5.20140522/ \
  | tidy -asxml \
  | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '*//_:a[position() > last() - 6]' -v '@href' -n
```

Comment: I had to sudo apt-get both tidy and xmlstarlet but, running your code spat back a bunch of errors...

Comment: Of course it did. Redirect stderr of both `tidy` and `xmlstarlet` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Comment: You put `2> /dev/null` after the command you want to silence, before any further piping, e.g. `... | tidy -asxml 2> /dev/null | ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
 grep href | tail -6 | sed 's/.*href="//;s/".*//'
```

But if you want to stick with your original code, it just needs to be loosened up a bit. Not all of the filenames coming from wget match the pattern the old sed command was using.  This seems to work:

```
grep '<a href=' | tail -6 | sed -e 's/.*\(rtma2p5.t[0-9]*z.2dvar.*.grb2\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/.*href="([^"]*)".*/{s//\1/;H};$!d;g;s/.*((\n[^\n]+){6})/\1/;s/\n//' file
```

Filter the file names into the hold space and at end-of-file retrieve the last six.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 curl -sL 'http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/rtma/prod/rtma2p5.20140522/?C=M;O=A' | grep -Po '(?<=href=").*?(?="[^\?])' | egrep -v '^(\?|/)' | head -6
```

execution:

```
curl -sL 'http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/rtma/prod/rtma2p5.20140522/?C=M;O=A' | grep -Po '(?<=href=").*?(?="[^\?])' | egrep -v '^(\?|/)' | head -6
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvaranl_nwrfc.grb2
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvarerr_nwrfc.grb2
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvarges_nwrfc.grb2
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvaranl_ndfd.grb2
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvarges_ndfd.grb2
rtma2p5.t00z.2dvarerr_ndfd.grb2
```

Explanation:

1-  `/?C=M;O=A` I added this at the end of the url so we can sort by latest modified

2- `grep -Po '(?<=href=").*?(?="[^\?])'` gets everything between `href"` and `"`

3- `egrep -v '^(\?|/)'` filters some undesired links

4- `head -6` prints only the first 6 lines